# navigationBar.translucent = YES not working in presented view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, translucency

Why navigationBar.translucent = YES; not working for making translucent nav bar in presented view controller?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

This is my view controller presenting code.

```
    SettingsViewController *vc = [[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewControllerNew" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navVc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    navVc.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    [self presentViewController:navVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but it is working in root view and navigated view controller. What's wrong?

Comment: your presented VC is embed in Navigation controller

Comment: Please explain. How to solve this?

Comment: by default Present VC not embed in Navigation VC, if you need to add one more navigation bar

Comment: How can i get translucent nav bar in presented VC?

Comment: final code is correct and fine

Comment: I used that line brother @Anbu, but doesn't work.

Comment: this one is correct `SettingsViewController *vc = [[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewControllerNew" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navVc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    navVc.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    [self presentViewController:navVc animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik is right here. Presented view controllers don't have navigation bar by default. In case you want to have them you have to add them to a navigation item and then present them.